# How to quickly change from one monitor to a next one in Gnome3.16

Tags: archlinux, multiple-monitors, hdmi, gnome-3, gnome-shell

I use Gnome 3.16 under archlinux and would like to know if there is a quick way to change the integrated monitor with an external one via HDMI. This is the way I have to go (in pictures):

First, you have to open the monitor menu (here in spanish).

[image]

Second, you need to open the submenu (where you can choose out of four options: Make this monitor the primary, secondary, show the same content, or turn it off) of your external monitor and choose the option to show the same content in both monitors.

[image]

Third, you need to open the submenu of your integrated monitor  and turn it off.

[image]

Does someone know an easier and faster way to do it, i.e., that as soon as you plug in the HDMI cable it automatically switches to the external monitor while turning off the integrated monitor and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is scriptable with `xrandr`. You can use the friendlier `arandr` to generate scripts that call `xrandr`. Run `arandr` twice, once for each config you wish to keep. Do a “Save As” to save the two `xrandr` scripts. Then you simply call the appropriate script whenever you want to switch monitors/configs. I name my scripts like `xr1` and `xr2` and have a hot-key menu (as part of window manager) to quickly invoke them (or any other script).

[image: screenshot of arandr]

Comment: @TilHund Did the arandr tool work to generate the xrandr script(s) for you?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you very much!